# Google direction API query limit

Tags: android, google-maps

Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Is this limitation depends on key or on user's phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though they haven't mentioned it anywhere, I think this is how it limits:

- Any user (ip-address ) making 2500 requests per day, or having weird automated request patterns are blocked.
- The key is noted. If many users with this key are found abusing the API's, the key is blocked.

Comment: Is this still true today?

Comment: Earlier in 2011 it was not update on the Google page, now you can see usage limits here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits